# How to take a backup or export Postgres Database through command prompt

Tags: postgresql

Till today,I am taking backup through PGAdmin. Now I want to create batch file and it should run on particular time daily through windows scheduler
Please help me for the commands for taking backup of Postgres database through command prompt

Comment: This is too broad. You should read the chapter about backup in the fine manual, which explains all that very well.

Comment: can u please share me that link

Comment: Sure, [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html) it is.